# Adding NewRelic PHP agent via Ansible

Tags: ansible, newrelic

I've been trying to install NewRelic agent for PHP on Amazon Linux 2 the "ansible way", but I cannot get it to work with either `rpm_key` or `yum_repository`. I've also tried just copying the repo file to `/etc/yum.repos.d/newrelic.repo`, but it's supposed to use a GPG key and the only one I found is [548C16BF.gpg](https://download.newrelic.com/) and at that point I felt this was getting to hacky.

My current setup is:

```yaml
- name: add the new relic repository
  # noqa 303
  command: rpm -Uvh http://yum.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/x86_64/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm
```

but that doesn't sit well with `ansible-lint` (hence the rule exception).

Am I missing something here or maybe my preconception of what the "ansible-way" would be is incorrect. Asking for a friend (with a lot of Ansible experience).

Answer (score 1):

To add the GPG key:

```
- name: Adding RPM key
  rpm_key:
   state: present
   key: https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg
```

and Add the repository:

```
- name: Add repository
  yum_repository:
    name: rewrelic
    description: Newrelic YUM repo
    baseurl: http://yum.newrelic.com/pub/newrelic/el5/x86_64/newrelic-repo-5-3.noarch.rpm
```

Finally install the yum:

```
- name: install Rewrelic
  yum:
    name: rewrelic
    state: present
```